# About Using Hibernate in a Web Application (J2EE)

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, project

I'm new in Java EE (J2EE) , i would like to build web application that store users and passwords in databases than they can login and login out , after that i want let them can add , delete and edit fields like in this pic:

**Table**
[image]

**Edit table**
[image]

Is there examples of that, thank you

Comment: Your question is too broad. And btw, J2EE changed its name in 2006.

Comment: What kind of example would that be? No example is going to magically make you understand how all this works, you'll still have to do the work of studying all related technologies - at which point you can do it yourself and don't need an example anymore.

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you tell me what technologies i need to build that web application. what i know now Hibernate role is to create database and managing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no specific technologies for building an application like that, there are hundreds of technologies in thousands of combinations that will build a simple CRUD web application. You have specified that you want to use Java EE, but even that is not specific enough: do you want to use Java as a front end technology (eg JSP, JSF, etc) or just for server side processing? I would recommend that you investigate front end frameworks/technologies, different types of databases and different architectural styles and decide which combination is right for your application. Only that can you begin to think about examples and tutorials that will show you how to put them together.

To give you a starting point, the flavour of the month in front end technologies seems to be javascript frameworks like AngularJS (prior to that java based technologies were preferred in many cases). You can use this to communicate with RESTful web services written in Java EE. NoSQL databases like MongoDB are popular at the moment, but you could use a more traditional relational database like MySQL. Both of these databases work well with hibernate.

Bear in mind that is just a starting point for your research and may not be appropriate for your application.

Comment: thank you for your answer , yes i want use JSP and servlet. but i am not sure how i would build that application.

Comment: ok, well that helps. You should be able to google tutorials for JSP + java + hibernate with various types of databases. I did a quick search and found a lot of reasonable looking tutorials. Have a look and see how you get on. If you have a specific problem while attempting to follow an example or tutorial post another question with as much detail as possible. People on here will always help with specific issues, but not so much with general questions and opinions.